# max no of tcp connections on a linux system

Tags: security, tcp, socket, limit

I know that `/etc/security/limits.conf` provides the persistent soft and hard limits for several values.

However, in the relevant list there is no indication about imposed limits on:

a) concurrent open tcp connections

b) number of unix domain sockets

Where and how can anyone set/get these?

Are these values interrelated somehow?

Answer (score 7):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332741/what-is-the-theoretical-maximum-number-of-open-tcp-connections-that-a-modern-lin specifies a theoretical maximum of 65,535 per user per server port, but a better method to determine your maximum is to find your maximum number of file descriptors for every socket connection must have one.  The configuration can be altered with [sysctl](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/sysctl.8.html), but the ceiling is normally over 300,000.